# Automatically Pairing A Bluetooth Remote to Android Tablet

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an unusual application, where I am trying to automatically pair a bluetooth remote to an Android tablet.  The caveat here is that the user has no access to the screen, so all of this has to happen programmatically.  I am using 4.2.X.  Here is what I have functioning:
1) App Launches on Startup
2) I added a listener to detect a new input device (of any kind) Once this occurs, I issue a toast indicating that a new input device is found and this utility app finishes - tested and works
3) If no input devices are found, the app goes into a Bluetooth discovery mode sequence for 10 tries - or until the receiver is called indicating that the device I am searching for is found - Tested and functions properly
4) From here, I want to pair the device and connect to it, so that it becomes registered as an input device --- I can do this manually but can't seem to do it programmatically.  It looks like the APIs pre-19(4.4) are a bit limited.  I tried using reflection to use the "createBond()" method - but that seems to not to work.  If I need to use 4.4, that would be OK.

Does anyone have any ideas on item 4?   I have read a lot of threads, but can't seem to find one that addresses this.

Comment: From what I've seen in my code and what I've read, there is no way to pair bluetooth devices without manual intervention. This is a security issue. In Android 4.2+, the bluetooth code in Android was changed and now it has fewer "hidden" features. One of the things that went away was being able to connect L2CAP sockets. You can still connect an insecure socket to a bluetooth address. I'm not sure that it will work with unbonded addresses. If you want a keyboard or other HID device to automatically bond, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: From your response and all of the threads I read, I came to the same conclusion.